# Making a for-loop in Python looping over C++ objects and methods more efficient

Tags: python, c++, for-loop

I'm looking for performance improvements in some for loops.

Basically, I loop over a dictionary containing some data (Dict) in order to plot graphs. The module that I use for plotting is ROOT (high-energy physics framework implemented in C++, doesn't matter here).

The dictionary contains +100k values, and for each value the range() argument typically is from 1-150, which means that the range() loop gets called a lot.
The ROOT module in python is basically a dictionary that links to the C++ implementation of ROOT, such that for every loop in the range() loop the code picks out a C++ object (hist2D) and applies a C++ method (Fill(,)) to it.

So if we neglect the whole ROOT module now, is there a way to make my range() loop for efficient? For 100k values the time it takes is about 10-15s, but if I have more data and then the time obviously increases.

```
for item in list:

    for index in Dict[item]:

        if Dict[item][index] == 0:  
            continue

        for n in range(int(Dict[item][index] * FillQuantityFactor)):  
            # Fill ROOT histogram
            hist2D.Fill(item, index)
```

I guess one problem is that in every range() (e.g. let's say the range is 150) loop, the C++ object hist2D gets called 150 times, whereas we only would need to call it 1 time and just use the method 150 times.
So without digging into the C++ of my analysis module (ROOT) is there anything that I can do to make this code faster?
I guess using xrange instead of range would also help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're just using range() to get a number for a for-loop then xrange should shave some time off, yes. Do you have docs for the python ROOT module you're using?

Comment: There is, but I don't think it will get you anywhere, because it's a quite massive framework (https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/guides/users-guide/ROOTUsersGuideA4.pdf, Reference Guide: https://root.cern.ch/root/html604/ClassIndex.html). And the ROOT method that I use is kind of a (necessary) work-around anyways.
What about the "calling-150 times", am I right with that?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can call the method of an object without referencing the object in python. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with C/C++ so I can't really help you there, sorry.

Comment: Previous comments are correct.  Use xrange and as many other generators as possible.  You've got a classic n² loop here, so unless you change that somehow it will never get really quick.  You could write some c++ to interact with Root natively, and then use SWIG to generate some python bindings around all of it.

Comment: But I guess in this small code example I can't use more generators, or not?